# Foreach loop and incrementing variable and output to css

Tags: php, css, for-loop, foreach

I use Kirby CMS as backend.
I want following structure for my html output:

```
<ul>

    <li class="link-1"><a href="/#">Link</a></li>

    <li class="link-2"><a href="/#">Link</a></li>

    <li class="link-3"><a href="/#">Link</a></li>

    <li class="link-4"><a href="/#">Link</a></li>

</ul>
```

I have following code:

```
<?php foreach($pages->visible() AS $p): ?>

<?php $nbr = $pages->countVisible()?>


<li class="link-<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $nbr; $i++){echo $i;} ?>">
    <a<?php echo ($p->isOpen()) ? ' class="active"' : '' ?> href="<?php echo $p->url() ?>"><?php echo html($p->title()) ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

But instead I only get the css class

> link-1234

in each of the links, so it is making the for loop, but I need only one number per foreach loop.

---

This code made it work:

```
<li class="link-<?php static $x=1; echo $x; $x++; ?>">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <li class="link-<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $nbr; $i++){echo $i;} ?>">
```

only loops inside that element

```
 <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $nbr; $i++){ 
echo "<li class=\"link-$i\">";
echo 'the rest of the line';
 } ?>
```

should loop the whole block

Comment: Please look at my edit; why it says _Undefined variable: i_? And when I first define $i with 0 or 1 it won't increase the number in the foreach loop.

Comment: @projektalex The code in the question edit looks like a butchered mess trying to be a `for` loop. Start with user1281385's loop, then modify loop *body* as desired.

Comment: I made it with this line of code: <li class="link-<?php static $x=1; echo $x; $x++; ?>">. It is everything what I needed.